# strange bit shifting result

Tags: ios, bit-shift

```
int64_t maskTestNum = (1ll << 63);
```

could someone explain why this prints as the value below?

> -9223372036854775808

I think the absolute value is right but why the minus sign?

Comment: Uh, it's a signed number, and you've shifted into the sign bit?

Comment: OK, ta... didn't know about the signed bit but makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an unsigned integer instead: uint64_t.